# Many to Many Condition

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to make a search condition in a table Many to Many, but Im having problems.
I want to search using Posts model and filter by User ID in likes(many to many) table.

Tables:
posts, users and likes(many to many)

Model Post.php Relation:

```
'user_likes' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Users', 'likes(post_id, user_id)'),
```

Search Condition in Post Controller:

```
$criteria->with='user_likes';
$criteria->condition='user_likes.id=1'; //Search posts that user id '1' liked.
$posts=Posts::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Error:

```
CDbCommand falhou ao executar o comando SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_likes.id' in 'where clause'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to try to help guys.
I discovered the problem.

When using findAll do not need to declare `$criteria->together=true;`, but if using CActiveDataProvider its necessary.

I hope this helps someone too ;)

Answer (score 1):

The table `user_likes` does not have a column `id`.

Is this what you mean?

```
$criteria->with='user_likes';
$criteria->condition='user_id=1'; //Search if user id '1' liked the post.
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this logic. But it did not work too: `CDbCommand falhou ao executar o comando SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_likes.user_id' in 'where clause'.`

Comment: Which columns are present in the `user_likes` table? And is the table name `user_likes` or just `likes`?

Comment: The table name is just `likes`, and have the columns `profile_id` and `user_id` related with foreign keys to tables `profiles` and `users`, respective.

Comment: CDbCommand falhou ao executar o comando SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'likes.user_id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: I guess my knowledge of the yii framework is a bit limited. But it seems that it uses the entire `likes.user_id` as column name, so it probably should just be `user_id`.